# Simple animation for floating action button in android?

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

I need a very simple explanation of how I can animate this 'add to cart' `FloatingActionButton` whenever it's clicked. All I want is a smooth 'left-right' or 'down-up' movement animation.

Please look at the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background">    

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add more explanation.What are u trying to achieve?

Comment: So I just want my floating action button to do a shake either up and down or left and right animation when it is clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) library. This library provide easy way to animate you views. There is lot of effects. For example

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada)
.duration(700)
.playOn(findViewById(R.id.edit_area));
```

Comment: @Irtaza Safi it seems to me that you can add your fab into the layout (for example linear layout) and also put them view you want to display there. Then you can set android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" to this layout

Comment: API looks cool.  Using the library to animate, when I reference a View  for android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton - using data binding `YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse).duration(700).playOn(mBinding.floatingActionButton);` -  the xml settings there (like `alpha`, `scaleX`, etc) are being lost.  One hack to resolve this is to update the xml back to it's defined settings in Java via `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { .. }, 700);` .. where delay allows duration to complete .. but still, for things like `scaleX`, where they get reset .. the "animation smoothness" is getting lost

Answer (score 6):

`floatingActionButton.animate().xBy(10).yBy(10);`

On its `onClick`! give coordinates as you want!

or

*shake.xml*  > res/anim/shake.xml (*no extra library need you can customize this xml*)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:duration="150"
        android:fromXDelta="-10%"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXDelta="10%"/>
</set>
```

..

```
final FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation anim = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(floatingActionButton.getContext(),  R.anim.shake);
        anim.setDuration(200L);
        floatingActionButton.startAnimation(anim);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a more straightforward solution

Comment: @Irtaza Safi I dont like 2 use libraries for a simple thing like this,but answers with libraries gets accepted quickly :| ,any way  my one is simple if you like feel free to  use it ^_^ good luck

Comment: I agree. It's just that when you're a noob in an area the library answers seem more straightforward. Your answer definitely helps me understand how it works in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/Scalified/fab

It has a left to right or top to bottom Moving animation

In your gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.scalified:fab:1.1.3'
}
```

in layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <com.scalified.fab.ActionButton 
            android:id="@+id/action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now for moving use:

```
 // And then find it within the content view:
ActionButton actionButton = (ActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_button);
// Initialize the moving distance
int distance = 100.0f // in density-independent pixels

// Move ActionButton left
actionButton.moveLeft(distance);

// Move ActionButton up
actionButton.moveUp(distance);

// Move ActionButton right
actionButton.moveRight(distance);

// Move ActionButton down
actionButton.moveDown(distance);
```